# Block grid starting from right bottom corner

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm looking for a nice CSS way to get an unordered list to always end in the bottom right corner. For example:

```
      ||  1  ||   2 
  3   ||  4  ||   5
```

In a normal block-grid i'm using floating list-items. I have been looking at flexbox for a solution but haven't come up with anything satisfying.

Adding one item to this list would produce a list like this:

```
  1   ||  2  ||   3 
  4   ||  5  ||   6
```

Another one would be

```
      ||     ||   1
  2   ||  3  ||   4 
  5   ||  6  ||   7
```

Comment: Can't you just use something like `width: 30%` in combination with `float: left`?

Comment: Adding a width 33.3333% and float left doesn't make the list end in the right bottom corner.

Comment: Do you always have 5 items? if not what is it going to look like? start from bottom right or end in bottom right?

Comment: No, the length is variable. Always end in the bottom right, I updated my question with an example with 6 items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use flexbox with `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse` and `flex-direction: row-reverse`. You can add as many additional children elements as you want. (note: I left the container height at the default)

```css
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .x {
    width: 302px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-basis: 0%;
  }
  .y {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div class="y">1</div>
  <div class="y">2</div>
  <div class="y">3</div>
  <div class="y">4</div>
  <div class="y">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do 'floats' in flexbox with usage of the **margin**.

If you want to float it to the right:

```
margin-left: auto;
```

Is this what you been looking for? Or am i getting it wrong:
http://codepen.io/powaznypowazny/pen/ZLdBxa

Comment: In the pen you link to you see three items on the top line and only two on the bottom. I want the bottom line always to be filled.

Comment: Please test it again @Jan_dh